# python: How to get latest file in a directory with certain pattern

Tags: python

I want the latest file in a directory with certain pattern. I can find the latest file but don't know how to include pattern. Please try to propose solution involving os library only.

```
def newest(DIR_PATH):
    files = os.listdir(DIR_PATH)
    FILE_LIST = [os.path.join(DIR_PATH, BASENAME) for BASENAME in files]
    return max(FILE_LIST, key=os.path.getctime)
```

The directory is having many kinds of files. For example consider below two kind of files.

```
xyz-2019-11-17_01-25-14.json
xyz-2019-11-17_01-25-14-trimmed.json
```

I want to get the latest file that does not end with '-trimmed.json'.Please suggest.

Comment: which file do you want? on what criteria do you want to choose the file?

Comment: @FlorianH I want xyz-2019-11-17_01-25-14.json this kind latest file.

Comment: if you need sophisticated pattern matching, only using `os` will be hard - you might want to go for `regex`

Comment: @Rishi Bansal. I downvoted the question because you wrote "When I list the latest file I get xyz-2019-11-17_01-25-14-trimmed.json but I want another one". That is extremly unclear and makes it hard to help you. Thats why i postet the comment with the question. Rephrase it to something like "i want to get the latest file that does not end with '-trimmed.json'" than your question is a lot clearer, people can easier help you and i remove my downvote :)

Comment: @mrfuppes here the pattern should be "not having trimmed" which can be done in this [os.path.join(DIR_PATH, BASENAME) for BASENAME in files] , just not getting the right code.

Comment: @FlorianH thanks for letting me know. What you said make sense and I have rephrased my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could simply go like this:

```
def newest(DIR_PATH):
    files = os.listdir(DIR_PATH)
    FILE_LIST = [os.path.join(DIR_PATH, BASENAME) for BASENAME in files if not BASENAME.endswith("trimmed.json")]
    return max(FILE_LIST, key=os.path.getctime)
```

Answer (score 1):

you could probably use

```py
import os
from pathlib import Path as makePath

def find_youngest(path, pattern, n=1):
    """
    find the file that matches a pattern and has the highest modification
    timestamp if there are multiple files that match the pattern.
    input:
        path, string or pathlib.Path, where to look for the file(s)
        pattern, string, pattern to look for in filename
        n, integer, how many to return. defaults to 1
    returns
        filename(s) of youngest file(s), including path.
        None if no file
    """
    assert n >= 1, "n must be greater equal 1."

    path = makePath(path)
    files = [makePath(f) for f in path.glob(pattern) if os.path.isfile(f)]
    sortfiles = sorted(files, key=lambda x: os.path.getmtime(x), reverse=True)

    if sortfiles:
        return sortfiles[:n]
    return None
```

Note: if you use `pathlib.Path.glob`, you can also use `regex` patterns for string matching.

A simple way to select files base on the occurance of a specific filename ending could be

```py
files = ['xyz-2019-11-17_01-25-14.json',
         'xyz-2019-11-17_01-25-14-trimmed.json']
select = [f for f in files if not f.endswith('-trimmed.json')]
# select
# Out[35]: ['xyz-2019-11-17_01-25-14.json']
```

Comment: Can you please suggest something involving os library only as i asked in my question. This is due to limitation on my productin server. Thanks for your help. thumbs up.

Answer (score 0):

There's a library called glob. Check it out.
https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html

Comment: that should be a comment ;-)

Comment: @MrFuppes he might not be allowed to make a comment with 11 reputation :)

Comment: sure, but it's not that hard to get to the point where you're allowd to comment.

Answer (score 0):

This solution is almost same as what was given here by "Florian H" with one minor difference, if the pattern is somewhere in between the filename where endswith is not relevant.

```
def newest(DIR_PATH):
    files = os.listdir(DIR_PATH)
    FILE_LIST = [os.path.join(DIR_PATH, BASENAME) for BASENAME in files if "trimmed" not in BASENAME]
    return max(FILE_LIST, key=os.path.getctime)
```